# Terraform shows unnecessary changes due to whitespace

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I have used jsonencode function to pass windows-keys in metadata of gcp compute instance.

```
  metadata = {
    serial-port-logging-enable = "TRUE"
    // Derived from https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/automate-pw-generation
    windows-keys = jsonencode(
      {
        email    = "example.user@example.com"
        expireOn = "2020-04-14T01:37:19Z"
        exponent = "AQAB"
        modulus  = "wgsquN4IBNPqIUnu+h/5Za1kujb2YRhX1vCQVQAkBwnWigcCqOBVfRa5JoZfx6KIvEXjWqa77jPvlsxM4WPqnDIM2qiK36up3SKkYwFjff6F2ni/ry8vrwXCX3sGZ1hbIHlK0O012HpA3ISeEswVZmX2X67naOvJXfY5v0hGPWqCADao+xVxrmxsZD4IWnKl1UaZzI5lhAzr8fw6utHwx1EZ/MSgsEki6tujcZfN+GUDRnmJGQSnPTXmsf7Q4DKreTZk49cuyB3prV91S0x3DYjCUpSXrkVy1Ha5XicGD/q+ystuFsJnrrhbNXJbpSjM6sjo/aduAkZJl4FmOt0R7Q=="
        userName = "example-user"
      }
    )
  }
```

It is showing me unnecessary changes due to whitespace as follows:

```
~ "windows-keys" = jsonencode( # whitespace changes
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Could you please show the changes? What is the unwanted behaviour that is happening?

Comment: Yes ofcourse.  it is showing me some changes between terraform scripts and state file due to whitespaces.

Comment: Can we see the actual changes it's suggesting? It might be that it's more than whitespace. Also could you edit your question so that the Terraform code forms a [mcve] please? This allows people to more easily reproduce your issue and then help you to find a solution to fixing it.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely fixable by either fixing your line endings, or in the provider you are using (as with https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/23928). Basically, the state and the to-be-applied re-encoded data are not binary equivalent, and therefore Terraform will think that an update is needed.

Providers can be configured to ignore changes if the JSON is effectively equal, even if there are some whitespace differences.